# keypad mouse movement too slow on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, xorg, mouse

From questions and answers I've seen this issue goes way back.  I'm attempting to use my wireless keyboard keypad (Logitech K360) for mouse movement and control.  The mouse cursor does move but too slowly to be useful. I've done the following:

1. in Universal Access turned on Mouse Keys
2. Installed xkbset and used the terminal command `$xkbset ma 60 10 10 5 2` which gives me and error:  XKB not supported for display: 0.
3. I've created and edited a file in /etc/X11/Xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf as follows:

   `Section "InputClass"
   Identifer "system-keyboard"
   MatchIsKeyboard "on"
   Option "XkbOptions" "kepad:pointerkeys"
   EndSection`
4. Used `input --list --short` to find my mouse id and Device Accel Constant Deceleration and played with those settings as suggested in other answers on this site.
5. Installed Solaar package for the Logitech Unifying Receiver hardware I have.

So far none of these have had any effect of the keypad mouse speed.

Please, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the speed of your mouse in Settings > Devices > Mouse and Touchpad > Mouse Speed

Comment: Thanks Graham, I did try that without success.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.10, I did steps 1 and 2 without success.
Then, I changed the max speed (the 4th number) to 100 and it worked.
That was way too fast so I changed it to 5 and it was good.

To summarize, I did:

- Activate mouse keys in Universal access
- Install `xkbset`
  `sudo apt-get install xkbset`
- Use `xkbset` with max speed 100
  `xkbset ma 60 20 10 10 100 10`
- Use `xkbset` with desired speed
  `xkbset ma 60 20 10 10 5 2`